# Extract CurrentRegion into email body

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

CurrentRegion is extracted but not shown in email body

```vb
Sub Draft()

    Dim myDataRng As Range
    Set myDataRng = Range("c2:c2")

    Dim data As String
    data = Range("B11").CurrentRegion.Select

    For Each Cell In myDataRng
        If Cell.Value > 0 Then
            Dim objOutlook As Object
            Set objOutlook =     CreateObject("outlook.application")

            Dim objEmail As Object
            Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

            Range("K2").Select

            With objEmail
                .SentOnBehalfOfName = "accounting@test.co.uk"
                .to = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                .Subject = ActiveCell.Offset(7, 0).Value
                .htmlbody = "Supplier Code " & " " & Cell.Offset(0, 0).Value & "<br>" & "Supplier Name: " & " " & Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value & "<br>" & "Currency " & " " & Cell.Offset(2, 0).Value & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Dear Supplier," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "A payment has been issued to you, as detailed below. " & "<br>" & data & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Kind Regards,<br>Johnny Grif <br>Accounts Assistant/Accounts Department" & "<br>" & "T:+44(0)1234 567 890" & "<br>" & "E:accounting@test.co.uk"
                .Save
            End With

            Set objOutlook = Nothing
        End If
    Next Cell

    Set myDataRng = Nothing
    Set objEmail = Nothing: Set objOutlook = Nothing
    MsgBox "Please check pyament advice in your draft folder!"

End Sub
```

The final outcome is like this.

*Dear Supplier,*

*A payment has been issued to you, as detailed below.*
*True*

*Kind Regards,*
*Johnny Grif*
*Accounts Assistant/Accounts Department*
*T:+44(0)1234 567 890*
*E:accounting@test.co.uk*

Below is the output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following code is the cause of the problem:

```
.htmlbody = "Supplier Code " & " " & Cell.Offset(0, 0).Value & "<br>" & "Supplier Name: " & " " & Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value & "<br>" & "Currency " & " " & Cell.Offset(2, 0).Value & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Dear Supplier," & "<br>" & "<br>" & 
"A payment has been issued to you, as detailed below. " & "<br>" & data & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Kind Regards,<br>Johnny Grif <br>Accounts Assistant/Accounts Department" & "<br>" & "T:+44(0)1234 567 890" & "<br>" & "E:accounting@test.co.uk"
```

First of all, the message body markup should be represented by a well formed HTML document/string.

Second, if you need to break the line in the code you need to use the underscore `_` character in the code to get the lines assembled correctly.

Third, I'd suggest breaking the code and trying to assemble the final from multiple pieces, so you could find out why the code doesn't work correctly.

Comment: 1+3 actually the code works but only the part of current region just shown as”true” but not the data. I deleted the underscore for this post only but it has in the original coding. So what’s the problem of the “data” part, I have google and tried to rectify but in vain, could you please give me a hand to tell me what’s wrong?Thank you very much.

Comment: Try to assemble a string before assigning it to the `HTMLBody` property. Do you get a valid string?

Comment: actually it's a table range with 3 rows and 7 columns, but it cannot be shown correctly, it just shows a word "true"

Comment: So, the problem is converting the data from Excel to a string value?

Comment: how can it shows as a table in email body,  just like i see it in Excel? even i change "dim data as string" to dim data as Range", the outcome is not correct.........